# Mockito ClassCastException - A mock cannot be cast

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a method in the class `AppleProcessor` which I would like to test:

```
public void process(Fruit fruit) {
    if(fruit.getType() == Fruit.APPLE) {
        fruitBasket.add(((AppleFruit) fruit).getApple());
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Note that Fruit is an interface with the method `getType()` which AppleFruit implements and also has a `getApple()` method.

My test looks like:

```
@Mock
FruitBasket fruitBasket;

@Mock
Fruit fruit;

@Mock
AppleFruit apple;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testAnAppleIsProcessed() {
    AppleProcessor appleProcessor = new AppleProcessoer();
    when(fruit.getType()).thenReturn(Fruit.APPLE);
    when(((AppleFruit) fruit).getApple()).thenReturn(apple);

    appleProcessor.process(fruit);

    verify(fruitBasket).add(isA(Apple.class));
}
```

However I get the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: package.fruit.Fruit$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b8254f54 cannot be cast to package.fruit.AppleFruit`

which comes from this line in the test

`when(((AppleFruit) fruit).getApple()).thenReturn(apple);`

Would anyone know how to resolve this so I can test my code?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you say

```
@Mock
Fruit fruit;
```

You tell Mockito: the `fruit` variable should be an instance of `Fruit`. Mockito will dynamically create a class which implements `Fruit` (this class is `Fruit$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b8254f54`), and create an instance of this class. There's no reason for this class to be an instance of `AppleFruit`, since you didn't tell Mockito that the object had to be of type AppleFruit.

Declare it as `AppleFruit`, and it will be of type `AppleFruit`.

Answer (score 15):

To anyone searching for this just include:

```
@Mock(extraInterfaces = {AppleFruit.class})
Fruit fruit;
```

Which will add an extra interface to the mock and the casting wont raise any exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Mockito can deal with mocked objects that are already casted at mocking time (assignment). However, it does not cast by itself a mocked object during code execution.

In other words(or better yet, code):

```
Fruit fruit = Mockito.mock(Applefruit.class);
```

Just do as JB Nizet said and you will be fine. I had a similar problem and his solution worked.

For this question it would be:

```
@Mock
FruitBasket fruitBasket;

@Mock
AppleFruit fruit; // changed here

@Mock
AppleFruit apple;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testAnAppleIsProcessed() {
    AppleProcessor appleProcessor = new AppleProcessoer();
    when(fruit.getType()).thenReturn(Fruit.APPLE);
    when(((AppleFruit) fruit).getApple()).thenReturn(apple);

    appleProcessor.process(fruit);

    verify(fruitBasket).add(isA(Apple.class));
}
```

That is all what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct mockito to return an object of subclass type, for a method which returns a super-class object. Then you won't need to tell mockito to cast the object.

Comment: An example of this would be very useful...  Unless you mean simply declare it as AppleFruit...

Answer (score 0):

Your mock object is enhanced by Mockito and it is not same as your class, so you can't type cast.

Comment: So is there not a way around it without not using a mock object?

Comment: There is definitely. I would suggest call the method with appleFruit instance, not fruit.

Answer (score 0):

@Mock(extraInterfaces) annotation worked with PowerMockito:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PowerMockitoTest {

    @Mock(extraInterfaces = {Apple.class})
    private Fruit fruit;


    @Test
    public void castingMock() {
        when(((Apple) fruit).isRed()).thenReturn(false);
        assert !fruit.isSweet();
    }

}

interface Fruit {

    public boolean isSweet();

}

class Apple implements Fruit {

    @Override
    public boolean isSweet() {
        return isRed();
    }

    public boolean isRed() {
        return true;
    }

}
```